# PyOWM 'Observation' object has no attribute 'observation'

Tags: python, attributeerror, openweathermap

This code is pulled directly from the PyOWM docs:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
owm = OWM('your-api-key')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
pressure_dict = mgr.weather_at_place('Berlin,DE').observation.pressure
pressure_dict['press']
pressure_dict['sea_level']
```

I have an API key that works. The package seems to work when I am calling temperatures from another attribute, but this code results in: `AttributeError: 'Observation' object has no attribute 'observation'` when run.

Any ideas as to what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyOWM author here - it's a bug in the docs (tracked and will be fixed)

The example should be:

```
from pyowm.owm import OWM
owm = OWM('your-api-key')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
pressure_dict = mgr.weather_at_place('Berlin,DE').weather.pressure  # 'weather', not 'observation'
pressure_dict['press']
pressure_dict['sea_level']
```

This is because `mgr.weather_at_place('Berlin,DE')` gives an `Observation` object which embeds a `Weather` object instance

Comment: changed AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'weather'